# style doesn't reflect what's in css

Tags: theming

On my page http://www.athleticedgefitness.com/, I added a drop down menu under Contact. The hover color is yellow but for some reason, I cannot find that color style in my colors.css. What I found is that the devtools show that the background color change is caused 
by a rule starting at line 44 in 
http://www.athleticedgefitness.com/sites/default/files/color/corporateclean-659c1a2d/colors.css?mp37st 
The rule is:

```
#header-menu ul.menu li ul.menu li a:hover, 
#header-menu ul.menu li.expanded ul.menu li.expanded a:hover, 
#header-menu ul.menu li.expanded ul.menu li.leaf a:hover, 
#navigation .block-superfish ul.sf-menu li li:hover, 
#navigation .block-superfish ul.sf-menu li li a:focus, #navigation 
.block-superfish ul.sf-menu li li a:hover, #navigation .block-superfish 
ul.sf-menu li li a:active  { background-color:#fbff24; }
```

But If I check in my colors.css, my rule actually looks like this:

```
#header-menu ul.menu li ul.menu li a:hover,
#header-menu ul.menu li.expanded ul.menu li.expanded a:hover,
#header-menu ul.menu li.expanded ul.menu li.leaf a:hover,
#navigation .block-superfish ul.sf-menu li li:hover,
#navigation .block-superfish ul.sf-menu li li a:focus, #navigation .block-superfish ul.sf-menu li li a:hover, #navigation .block-superfish ul.sf-menu li li a:active  { background-color:#1b1b1b; }
```

I have tried to clear the caches and everything but that didn't help either, any recommendations? This is in Drupal 7.x with the Corporateclean theme.

Thank you!

Comment: Well, there is webserver's cache, proxy cache, browser cache, sometimes Boost cache, ngnx or varnish cache... it's hard to be sure you cleared them all.

Comment: @Molot, yes, I also used different browsers to confirm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added and configured Nice Menus - can configure the style sheets properly with that, unsure why that yellow wouldn't disappear...

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the css file route (Chrome will show that in the dev tool) that the website is reading? I use superfish as well, there are some css files for the menu bar in '.../sites/all/superfish/css/', but I also have my overriding style in my custom theme folder. Are you sure the browser is linking to the css file that you think it is linking to?

And, that happened to me once, probably is not your case, but I once forgot to save my css after editing it :P

Good luck.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean with the file route, canyou be more descriptive please? I'm not using superfish thus, there's no /sites/all/superfish/ - should I be using superfish? directory for my site... I did save my css file! :)

Comment: If you're not using Superfish it seems strange that you have CSS rules like `#navigation .block-superfish`...

Comment: @Clive I do not have a module superfish installed nor have I ever heard of that module at all before this thread...

Comment: @the_summer_bee I now installed and enabled superfish just to see what's happening but I still don't have a /sites/all/superfish/ directory, in my /sites/all/ dir, there's only libraries, modules & themes... any other idea? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, where did you get the css file from then? did you write it, or is it come with any other themes or modules? It is not important whether or not you have used superfish. The key thing is, the css file you think you are using probably is not the one the website is actually linking to.

Comment: It is worth checking all the css files you have there and make sure you are editing the right one.